# Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender Add-on in 2.80?

Tags: add-on

Does anyone know why the Paper-Model add-on is not in the Beta 2.8 ?
And Will it be back in the final version of 2.80 ?

Comment: Have you searched in the add-on panel for it

Comment: It is Ok to Blender 2.8. Only the manual is not update yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the guy who makes the plug-in didn’t have time to update the code for the 2.8 beta.

His words: "It is, and will be in 2.80 release.
I just didn't finish the port, so these changes are not commited yet."

You can follow here: https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/issues/62